# Using matrix rows as index range on a vector?

Tags: matlab

I have this matrix:

```
A = [1 3
    5 7
    9 10];
```

And this vector:

```
B = zeros(1,10);
```

Now I want to change the elements in the ranges of `[1:3]`,`[5:7]` and `[9:10]` to **1** . 
So, to get this:

```
C = [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1];
```

---

I tried:

```
B(A(:,1):A(:,2)) = 1;
```

but it just changes the zeros in the first range.

Can it be done without a `for` loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The first column of `A` are starting positions and the second one are ending positions of each sequence of 1s. To denote a beginning use `1` and for the end `-1`, then `cumsum()`.

```
% Preallocate
N = 10;
B = zeros(1,N);

B(A(:,1)) = 1
B =
     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0
B(A(:,2)+1) = -1
B =
     1     0     0    -1     1     0     0    -1     1     0    -1
B = cumsum(B)
B =
     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     0
B(1:N)
ans =
     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this be appropriate?

```
>> f = @(x)(any(A(:,1)<=x & x<=A(:,2)));
>> i = 1:length(B)

i =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> arrayfun(f,i)

ans =

     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this:

```
B([A(1,1):A(1,2) A(2,1):A(2,2) A(3,1):A(3,2)]) = 1;
```

Comment: No, I can't. This was a simple example. In reality, `A` has a lot more rows than this. So, this is impractical.